# Do not want to run maven-dependency-plugin when user specifies -DskipTests=true

Tags: javascript, maven, dependency-management

We use Jasmine Spec test to test our JS code. For running the specs we use maven-dependency-plugin to download openui5 dependencies from Nexus, unzipping them into our local folder. The problem we are facing is the 'zip' is huge and hence we ***don't want*** to run this 'maven-dependency-plugin' execution step when user has specified -DskipTests=true. Is there a way to specify the same. Our pom looks something like:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-ui5</id>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
                                <artifactId>xxxxxx</artifactId>
                                <version>xxxxxx</version>
                                <classifier>static</classifier>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency/openui5</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a skip parameter on unpack goal of the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html)

You will need to skip on the project property, akin to this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ...
            <configuration>
               <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
               ... 
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```